# PhoneJS: SlideOut layout add buttons to toolbar

Tags: phonejs

I'm building a layout using PhoneJS, I need to add more buttons to the toolbar that contains the "Menu" button and the title.

I'd like to add a "Write" button on the right.
I can't find documentation about this task, how can I perform it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use recommendations from [Views and Layouts -> Add Commands to Views](http://phonejs.devexpress.com/Documentation/Howto/Views_and_Layouts#Add_Commands_to_Views) article to get started.

Is this what you are looking for?